# How do people create trigonometric questions from scratch?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, complex-numbers

I'm interested in how people just generate a question from scratch,(i'm preparing for indian highschool level competitive exam "iitjee"), i think people don't just start writing random stuff and label that as a question but, there are only four things i can think of

1. they are using geometry
2. some sort of inequalities
3. complex numbers
4. somehow algebra
   But i don't know how to generate trig questions from it, if anyone could help in giving some examples and thought processes it would be much appreciated.

(Seen my teacher creating questions from **Jensens inequality, mth power theorem,am-gm-hm-qm inequality,complex number**)

(It was my first time asking questions please ignore if any mistakes are made)

Thank you!

Comment: They likely know a lot more advanced theory that you're aware of. EG The "somehow algebra" could be an understanding of [Chevyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) that provides information about sums and products of $ \cos k\pi/n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let we want to create a trigonometric inequality with using Jensen.

Note $\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+k\sin\gamma$, where $k$, $\alpha,$ $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are positives such that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi.$

Since $\sin$ is a concave function on $[0,\pi]$, by Jensen we obtain:
$$\sin\alpha+\sin\beta\leq2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}=2\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}$$ and we can try to find a rational value of $k$ for which an expression $2\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}+k\sin\gamma$ gets a rational maximal value.

We obtain $$\left(2\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}+k\sin\gamma\right)'=-\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}+k\cos\gamma=-\left(2k\sin^2\frac{\gamma}{2}+\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}-k\right)$$ and we want that it should be equal to zero for some non trivial value of $\gamma.$

If $\gamma=\frac{\pi}{3}$, so we obtain $k=1$ and it's not so interesting.

But for $\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}=\frac{3}{5}$(because we want that $\sin\gamma$, $\sin\alpha$ and $\sin\beta$ would be rational numbers) we obtain $k=\frac{15}{7}$ and we got the following problem.

> For any triangle prove that:
> $$\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\frac{15}{7}\sin\gamma\leq\frac{128}{35}.$$

Comment: thanks for answering! this one was very easy to follow! have a nice day sir.

Comment: @GREED SKITH You are welcome!

Answer (score 6):

I can to show, how I created one inequality for our last camp.

Let me take the following expression: $\sqrt{a^2+bc}$ and we see that $$(a^2+bc)(b+c)=a^2b+a^2c+b^2c+c^2b=$$we got very many squares and we'll try to use it:
$$=b(c^2+a^2)+c(a^2+b^2).$$
Also, we want to remove a radical, but by C-S we obtain another radicals:
$$b(c^2+a^2)+c(a^2+b^2)=\frac{(b+c)(b(c^2+a^2)+c(a^2+b^2))}{b+c}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(b\sqrt{c^2+a^2}+c\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)^2}{b+c}.$$
Also, we see that $a^2+b^2$ it's a cyclic forward moving of $c^2+a^2
$ and we can use it by the following way:
$$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+bc}{b^2+c^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{(a^2+bc)(b+c)}{(b^2+c^2)(b+c)}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{(b+c)(b(c^2+a^2)+c(a^2+b^2))}{(b^2+c^2)(b+c)^2}}\geq\frac{b\sqrt{c^2+a^2}+c\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{(b+c)\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$$ and we got a possibility to remove $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and similar by AM-GM, which gives the following:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a^2+bc}{b^2+c^2}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{(b+c)(b(c^2+a^2)+c(a^2+b^2))}{(b^2+c^2)(b+c)^2}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{b\sqrt{c^2+a^2}+c\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{(b+c)\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\sqrt{\frac{b^2+c^2}{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{c}{b+c}\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2+c^2}}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ac}{(a+b)(b+c)}}=2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{bc}{(a+c)(b+c)}}$$ and  your teacher send you:

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
> $$\sqrt{\tfrac{a^2+bc}{b^2+c^2}}+\sqrt{\tfrac{b^2+ca}{c^2+a^2}}+\sqrt{\tfrac{c^2+ab}{a^2+b^2}}\geq2\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{bc}{(a+b)(a+c)}}+\sqrt{\tfrac{ca}{(b+c)(b+a)}}+\sqrt{\tfrac{ab}{(c+a)(c+b)}}\right).$$

By the similar way we can create an inequality with geometry, trigonometry, Jensen, P-M, complex numbers and more.

Say me, which of them you want to use and I'll create a problem and I'll explain, how I created it.

Say about two or maximum three things, otherwise it looses the sense.

Comment: (Wow that was awesome manipulations i learned quite a bit of application!) [[If you have spare time can you try making a bit easier question with trigo and jensens inq]]